# Deploying CSS with Jekyll and Octopress

Tags: css, jekyll, octopress

I am setting up an Octopress blog right now, and there's one thing I'm having some trouble with.

I can post on the blog after I've added a Markdown-file in the _posts folder like this:

```
rake generate
rake deploy
```

And it works fine with posts, but when I edit CSS in the sass > custom folder and generate/deploy, the edits are not shown on the live blog! When I open screen.css on the live server, everything seems to be fine - all my edits are there. But when I view the same file in Developer Tools on Chrome - the edits are not present.

It this some kind of caching issue?

Any hints on how to go about this is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: What happens when you open the page in incognito mode (disables cache etc.)?

Comment: It actually works when I do that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a caching issue. You'll need to modify the HTTP Headers sent with your static resources. There are lots of documents on caching out there, so I'm not going to repeat those here.

(WARNING: Shameless self-promotion ahoy!)

However, I will recommend that you version your static files so that you can aggressively cache them and not have to worry about making sure you're on the latest. I wrote an [article with some rake tasks](http://www.eriwen.com/performance/make-octopress-fast/) that optimize and version assets and then update the version in my `head.html` include. This is what my blog does.

I've also been meaning to try out the new [Jekyll Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/matthodan/jekyll-asset-pipeline) that might do this for you. You might give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I have running on Octopress for a while and trying to dissect its parts. I believe it might be some configuration in the source folder that is not taking into account the sass/custom. Maybe in source/_includes. Otherwise try to apply those changes in source/stylesheets/screen.css. Unfortunately many folks that contributed themes are not placing the code in the correct custom folders according to the official documentation. But also the official documentation is very outdated.